# Function destroy window unknown (c++ opencv Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opencv

my compiler says: destroyWindow isn't an element of cv. (hope i translated it correctly)

i included opencv/highgui.h and actually there exists:
destroy window and all the trackers associated with it 
CVAPI(void) cvDestroyWindow( const char* name );

I am using the latest version of opencv.

Comment: Docs (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/user_interface.html#destroywindow) says, it should be `DestroyWindow` (with capital `D`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this function exists within the namespace `cv` as:

```
void destroyWindow(const string& winname)
```

And you should include:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

which is the appropriate header to add when working with the C++ interface of OpenCV. If you need samples, check `samples/cpp/ffilldemo.cpp` (can be found inside OpenCV's source code).